# Drag and drop with tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I try to drag and drop some div but before dragging them I display a tooltip on mouse over.

In firefox it works as expected but in Chrome when the drag start, the div is too big and contains some funny things: not only its content but also all the windows part that was behind the tooltip (red part in image).

[image]

```
<div class="tooltip" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31"
    onmousedown="mouseDown();">
    Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="ttt">Tooltip text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full example at: https://jsfiddle.net/dfs3ao13/5/

PS: tooltip works only once in the fiddle (not visible after one drag). You may have to refresh the page

Comment: Whats the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do not have a big div with wierd things inside in Chrome

Comment: can we see an image, it is not clear what you are experiencing

Comment: @randomguy04 image added

Comment: Let me know more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Chrome bug: when draggable element starts dragging, the drag-image of dragging element not only include its content, but also include all page content below that element's absolute child-nodes (in this case, the tooltip). However, after some searching, I can't find any bug report related with this issue.

This issue can have a workaround by 2 steps:

1. When element starts dragging, make tooltip's height as `0`. In this way, the tooltip won't mask any page content. Also, make `display` as `none` so that the tooltip won't be in the drag-image
2. When drag end, put tooltip's height as `auto` and put its `display` back to `block`.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/cyhq3dqo/8/). Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the given fiddle is not working: the tooltip is not hidden while draging.

Comment: @Benjamin ah, I see what you need now. The answer has been edited and the jsfiddle has been updated.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion with visibility: hidden + size at 0. Your solution works too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem where the drag preview snapshots whatever is behind the draggable element in chrome

This can be resolved by adding styles that force the draggable element to be considered by the browser to be on its own composite layer, so the snapshot only attempts to capture that layer during snapshot for preview

Any of the CSS transform rules that pass it off to the GPU will accomplish that. Try adding a classname that does this to your draggable element should do the trick. It won't affect the appearance so can be added permanently even when not dragging

```
.draggable { 
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Almost works but the tooltip is now hidden by the div where the draggable object should be dropped. shaochuancs gives a correct answer

Comment: No probs, this is a handy trick to know anyway, glad its solved